# UIScrollview with size class and auto layout selected

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

In my app, I am using standard xib files rather than a storyboard and all of the views have the universal size class option selected. When I do the design work, I always work in the any.any frame.

All views are set to use auto layout and size classes.

For just about everything, this works a treat.

The problem comes if I have a `UIScrollView` in the view. It looks fine in any,any and when I move to compact,any the view looks fine with everything in the right place.

However, if I then test on the device, the scrollview is much larger than the device view, so something has gone amiss.

Adding in `scrlView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true;` sorts the problem for the scrollview, but then messes up the rest of the view outside of the scrollview.

The scrollview is set to have scrolling enabled and bounces. Everything else is as it comes when you add the scrollview.

It looks as if the scrollview (on deployment) is set to still be any,any rather than compact,any.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does it work properly on the simulator and look correct in the Preview panel? From the information you have given it sounds like the constraints are wrong and the scroll view is not pinned properly to the edges of the views.

Comment: It shows correctly in the preview which is even more annoying :(

Comment: How about the simulator? I have found the preview to be less than accurate. Any constraint satisfy errors in the console?

Comment: Simulator shows the behaviour I've described. No errors showing in the console either. I do add buttons within the app to the scrollview, but they don't exceed the view

Comment: Sounds like your constraints are wrong. Esp since turning on auto constraints has an effect. You want that as FALSE really. Make sure that the full view hierarchy is pinned on all sides. So check your scroll view is pinned on all sides and the container view (if any) is also pinned on all sides all the way up the view tree.